# Scripts not recognizing variable as ID

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I have a script that writes the ID of a file it created into a Google Sheet.

In another script I am referencing the same range in the original sheet with the ID in it. I am using it to fill in a `.getFileById` to grab a document.

I want to use that variable to get `MailApp` to send the document as a PDF attachment.

When I try to use the variable, I get the following error message.

> No item with the given ID could be found, or you do not have permission to access it.

The first thing I did was make sure the value in the spreadsheet had the `" "` around it. I set it up to add that in the first script.
I have tried using `'` and `"`.  I have added those in the first script and in the second script in variation.

I've been logging the value of `newdoc` after I call it, and it returns it as `"1TNk0pydxxD5VBg6zcQ8Jdn1L6T8jL5jCHY0vTt9BLIE"` or similar.

It still hangs up when I come to setting the variable as the ID.

If I copy and past the exact same info in the cell in the sheet in the place where I would put the variable, it works.

At the request of a coworker I also wrote a line in to see if I could put that value in another cell.  It wrote the right ID.

From the Script where I store the variable:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('17jXy9IlLt8C41tWEG5iQR31GjzOftlJs73y2L_0ZWNM');
var cell = ss.getRange("P"+(i+2));
cell.setValue('"'+documentID+'"');
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
```

And from the script where I try to use that variable:

```
function EmailReport() {
var tactics = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get('17jXy9IlLt8C41tWEG5iQR31GjzOftlJs73y2L_0ZWNM', 'A2:P3');

var i = 0; i < tactics.values.length;

var customer = tactics.values[i][0];
var pcname = tactics.values[i][1];
var custID = tactics.values[i][14];
var newdoc = tactics.values[i][15];

Logger.log('DocumentID '+newdoc)    

var blob = '<p>As a part of your Computer Maintenance Service Agreement with TAS, we have created a  report for your computer.  Attached is the report on the health of your PC.<p>If you have any questions, you can call or e-mail me.

var file = DriveApp.getFileById(newdoc)

Logger.log('Document ID 2 '+file)

MailApp.sendEmail(custID, 'Monthly Computer Health Check', custID, {
htmlBody:('Dear ' + customer + blob),
attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)]
});
}
```

I'm expecting it to put the string into the `.getFileById()` command and then have it get that file, which I can then use to put it in my email as a PDF below.

What I get instead is

> 'No item with the given ID could be found, or you do not have permission to access it. (line 35, file "Code")'

But it works if I manually copy and paste the exact info.

Comment: Can I ask you about the value of `newdoc` when the error occurs and the value of `the exact info?

Comment: In the `cell.setValue('"'+documentID+'"');` you don't need the quotes if the value is already stored as a String, if you have, for example, `var documentID = "ID_HERE"` then you would only need to call `cell.setValue(documentID);` if you write it like that, the actual string will have a value of `""ID_HERE""` which will not be recognized as a valid ID

Comment: @AMolina I took off the bit of code adding the " when I stored the info. I didn't know that the scripts would automatically add those to a string. I'm new at this, and remembering to close off everything when writing it the first time was being beaten into me.  I thought I'd have to keep doing it in this case.

Comment: @Tanaike The value of     newdoc is the (as shown in the logger) is   
  "DocsIdValue" with the quotation marks.

Comment: Don't worry about it, everybody starts by learning!, I'm gonna post an answer with what I said in the comment for documentation. For future reference, the "" is how you clarify that a value is a string, but if you have a string variable holding some content, the compiler already knows how to treat it, ie. it will know that it has to have the ""

Comment: @Stephen S Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting for documentation.

In the `cell.setValue('"'+documentID+'"');` you don't need the quotes if the value is already stored as a String, if you have, for example, `var documentID = "ID_HERE"` then you would only need to call `cell.setValue(documentID);`.

If you write it with `('"'+documentID+'"')`, the actual string will have a value of `""ID_HERE""` which will not be recognized as a valid ID.